# line return in javascript

Tags: javascript

im trying to make this box stay one one width at 150px but how do i get text that is retrived that is longer that that return text to the next line instead of expand the div.

```
       <div id="page" style="position:absolute; float:right; top:500px; right:0px; background-color:#F5F5F5; color: #F6221D; font-size:12px; width:150;">
        <h2>ShoutOut</h2>

        <form method="post" action="shout.php">
            <strong>Message:</strong>
          <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="message" /><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <div id="shout" style="padding:0 10px 0; width:150; height:170px;; overflow-y:auto;">

        </div>
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //populating shoutbox the first time
    refresh_shoutbox();
    // recurring refresh every 15 seconds
    setInterval("refresh_shoutbox()", 15000);

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        // getting the values that user typed
        var name    = $("#name").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        // forming the queryString
        var data            = 'name='+ name +'&message='+ message;

        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shout.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
                $("#shout").slideToggle(500, function(){
                    $(this).html(html).slideToggle(500);
                    $("#message").val("");
                });
          }
        });    
        return false;
    });
});

function refresh_shoutbox() {
    var data = 'refresh=1';

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shout.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
                $("#shout").html(html);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this style to the DIV:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Comment: works well for words think this was what i was looking for. is there something like this for letters so if its one continuous line of text e.g. difjaslkdfjsadlkfjasdlkfjsdalkfjasdlkfjsaldkfjslkdfjsldfkjsl

Comment: then it will wrap that on the the next line?

Comment: I think this does that, doesn't it? It says "break-word," so I'm assuming that it will break a long word in order to wrap it.

Comment: @John: Just checked, and I think this does exactly what you need it to. See this article for details: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Comment: yep sorry tried again and works a treat. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your CSS:

```
width:150;
```

should be:

```
width:150px;
```

Comment: oh woops. new it was messy :/ thanks

Comment: @George Cummins: Does not specifying pixels cause this behavior? As I understand it, you no longer need to declare the size in pixels. You may be right, but I'm curious about the rationale behind your answer.

Comment: @James Johnson: The OP said "im trying to make this box stay one one width at 150px" so a pixel-width specification is the right answer. Also, [according to W3.org](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/width), units should be specified when using a length.

Comment: In firefox 6, setting the units makes the page work properly, whereas it does not work without the units.  So I'd say George nailed it.

Comment: @George Cummins: Huh, that's interesting. I was voted down recently for saying that units should be declared. If you're correct (which I think you are), then I feel jipped ;)

Comment: @James Johnson: Was your answer in the context of inline CSS (like this one) or in a Javascript/jQuery statement?

Comment: @George Cummins: Inline CSS on the div was what I was thinking. I suppose it could work either way though. Adding it directly to the div would be the more practical solution though.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: @VisioN, while the correct answer reveals that 'px' was left out, I am not sure this should be classified as a typo as I stated in the original version of this answer. As James and James Johnson illustrate above, it is not yet common knowledge that the unit identifier must be included.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Yeah, I've read the comments, and I'm still not sure how this question can help someone. Canonically the `px` (or other units) should be added to the numeric values in the styles (except `z-index`), and the OP confirmed that `this worked`.

Comment: @VisioN Fair enough. I've added my close vote. Thanks for your efforts!